# How to ask v-select to return the select string to use it to run a function from where is it call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

So I want to this call

```
  <ValidWordList
    :items="answer.WordList"
    :labelText="answer.WordList.length + ' Words'"
  
  /></template>
```

to return the select string from the items array to run this function after a string is selected

```
function select(word: string) {
  console.log(word)
  answer.value = word
}
```

and here is the component

```
<template>
  <v-select :items="items" return string :label="labelText" ></v-select>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
export interface Props {
  items?: string[]
  labelText: string
}

const props = defineProps({
  items: {
    type: Array,
    default: ''
  },
  labelText: {
    type: String,
    default: ' Words'
  }
})
</script>
```

Honestly, I'm not sure what to do and how to make it work and I tried to add @input and @change and emit it back but nothing seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `v-model` to do bind the change and use `emit` to emit a custom event. And sense that event in the parent.

Like this
custom component

```
<template>
      <v-select
            label="Select"
            v-model="msg"
            :items="['California', 'Colorado', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Texas', 'Wyoming']"
        return-object
            ></v-select>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue';
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'change', value: string): void
}>()
  const msg = ref('');
  function selectF() {
    console.log('msg', msg.value)
    emit('change', msg.value)
  }
  watchEffect(() => selectF())

</script>
```

and the parent

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <Comp @change="onChange" />
      Selected Item - {{select}}
      
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import Comp from './Comp.vue';
  const select = ref('');
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    function onChange(e) {
    console.log('e', e);
    select.value = e
    }
    Comp

</script>
```

I've made a example in the vuetify playground [code](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).